# Django Rest Framework AttributeError: module 'coreapi' has no attribute 'Client'

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-testing, django-tests

I am trying to run tests for api that worked before. Test.py looks like following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase


class ApiUserTest(APITestCase):
    """
    python manage.py test .\apps\api\api_user

    API urls:
    api_user/login/
    api_user/logout/
    api_user/register/
    api_user/change_password/

    """
    def setUp(self):
        ...

    def test_user_register(self):
        ...
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
PS F:\ComputerShop> python manage.py test .\apps\api\api_user
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E
======================================================================
ERROR: api.api_user.tests (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: api.api_user.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Emil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Users\Emil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "F:\ComputerShop\apps\api\api_user\tests.py", line 3, in <module>
    from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
  File "F:\ComputerShop\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 123, in <module>
    class CoreAPIClient(coreapi.Client):
AttributeError: module 'coreapi' has no attribute 'Client'
```

I also tried to run tests on a known working project, but they did not start there either.
I've tried to reinstalling the rest framework but it doesn't help. I use virtual environment in the project

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem you should install next packages:
pip install coreapi pyyaml

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).